# Transfer "labels" and "values" from SPSS to R, store and re-apply

Tags: r, label, spss

I have inherited a massive (~200 variables) dataset that used to be processed in SPSS in which each variable can have up to 50+ levels that are "coded", not labelled. See below:

```
df$CountryOfBirth
[1] 1201 1201 2010 9124 1101 4105 1101
```

In this case, each number corresponds to a country (e.g., 1201 = England; 1101 = France). Doing the replacement in this case is easy given that for one "code" I have one "label".

The issue is that in this dataset I also have other "questionnaire-like" variables that sometimes share the same levels, sometimes not. In addition these questions have multiple repetitions that correspond to the same question basically asked at different moment of the year (TiredQuestion1; TiredQuestion2; TiredQuestion3... )

```
df$TiredQuestion1
[1] 1 2 2 3 1 2 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 4

Labels:
 value                label
     1     None of the time
     2 A little of the time
     3     Some of the time
     4     Most of the time
     5      All of the time



df$LivingQuestion1
[1] 4 2 5 4 5 5 5 4

Labels:
 value                              label
     1                     Very satisfied
     2                      dissatisfied 
     3 neither satisfied nor dissatisfied
     4                          satisfied
     5                          very good
```

As you can see above, with packages like `haven()`, `sjlabelled()` I managed to extract from SPSS the dataframe including the values and labels for each variable.

Given that this dataset is updated almost every week with new entries, I am trying to get those values and labels for each variable, store them and match them onto the "new" variables as the data set gets updated (see below).

```
df$TiredQuestion1
[1] "None of the time" "A little of the time" "A little of the time" "Some of the time"

Labels:
 value                label
     1     None of the time
     2 A little of the time
     3     Some of the time
     4     Most of the time
     5      All of the time


df$CountryOfBirth
[1] "England" "France" "Spain" "Bosnia"

Labels:
 value                label
     1101     England
     2010     France
     3010     Spain
     5010     Bosnia
     ...
```

I have tried to use `codebook()`, `memisc()` and `asciiSetupReader()` without success.
I would be more than happy if I could have your thoughts on this, as I am starting to think that I am tackling this issue the wrong way.

Thanks in advance,
Julien

Comment: like this? `l <- attr(df$CountryOfBirth, 'labels'); factor(NA, l, names(l))`

Comment: Thanks! Would it make sense then to store each variable level (labels and values) in a vector and then create a list() like `codebook <- list(l,m)` ? 
The issue with this method is that it retrieves both the label and value if I call `codebook[[1]][2]` . Therefore, I'm unsure how to use this to then match again to a new DF with the same variables.